# Run-Time Error 5 when creating a pivot table with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a pivot table but I keep running into an error.
Here is my code so far.

```
Sub Practice()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pvtc As PivotCache
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim str As String

str = "Jul 26"

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

'Create Pivot Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
ws.Name = str
    
'Create Pivot Cache
Set pvtc = wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
SourceData:="Lignes!" & wb.Sheets("Lignes").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Address)
    
'Create Pivot Table
Set pvt = pvtc.CreatePivotTable( _
TableDestination:=ws.Name & "!" & ws.Cells(1, 1).Address, _
TableName:="Table1") 

End Sub
```

The error occurs specifically at the last step when I create the pivot table.
What's wrong with it?

Edit: It was suggested I wrap my sheet name with single quotes (since it contains a space) if I pass a string to the TableDestination argument. I tried this

```
'Create Pivot Table
Set pvt = pvtc.CreatePivotTable( _
TableDestination:="'" & ws.Name & "'!A1", _
TableName:="Table1")
```

but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: If you're getting an error, then it seems like `TableDestination` does *not* accept a `String`. In any case, you should use a `Range` as i posted in the answer, and as the docs show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to just use a `Range` object here:

```vb
TableDestination:=ws.Cells(1,1)
```

Comment: It worked!  
  
However, I read that passing range objects to pivot table methods may cause a type mismatch error and that's why it is recommended to pass the address as a string.

Comment: That is the case for the `SourceData` argument in `PivotCaches.Create`. Here a `Range` object is fine. See the code snippet in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotcache.createpivottable).

Comment: I've never tried using a `String` for `TableDestination`, but if it can accept a string, the problem with your approach is that you need a single quote before and after the sheet name (since the sheet name contains a space).

Comment: I tried implementing your suggestion with my string approach, however I am still getting the error. I'll edit my post since comments don't support line breaks.

Comment: Happy days! It's true, the string requirement appears to only concern the pivot cache creation. I'll pass a range then. Makes the code more parsimonious too!